# Factored polynomial sanity check.

Tags: polynomials

If I have a factored quartic polynomial in a function such as:

$f(0)=6 - A(x-2)(x+1)(x-3)(x+4)$

In the form of $f(x) = A(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$

I would like to know how to to graph it in Wolfram Alpha or Mac OS Grapher / similar apps to check my hand working out. How would I enter it in to confirm my answer?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. You can learn the typesetting with "MathJax" or by searching for LaTeX online.

Answer (score 0):

You can type it first in its original form and then take minus the factored form and see what gives you for example:

> x^2 - 1 - (x+1)(x-1)

This would give you answer 0 in wolfram alpha. If you made an error you would get something else than 0.

If you just want to graph it you can do this with the plot command:

> plot x^2 - 1

Or if you want specific interval of x:

> plot x^2-1 for x \in [-10,10]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understand that by taking the expanded from the factored would equal zero in wolfram. I would like to be able to graph the actual equation without figuring out what A is equal to.

Comment: Thanks again, but that only plots the polynomial without figuring out what the value of A is. Which could have many different answers to my understanding. The long hand way is to set $f(0)=0$ and plug into the equation in the form of $f(0)=A(0-2)(0+1)(0-3)(0+4)$ which equals $f(0)=A(24)$ then plug in the original value $f(6)=A(24)$ Divide both side by 24 to get the value of $A=6/24$ or $A=1/4$. You then plug this into your Polynomial to get $f(0)=1/4(x−2)(x+1)(x−3)(x+4)$ knowing that we see that when graphed, when $x=0$ that $y=6$. Hope this clarifies my question better.

Comment: Then you can edit your question by hitting the edit button under it so it better reflects what you actually want help with.